# IPFS failed to start in Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, ipfs

I am a newbie in IPFS. I am trying to install and run the IPFS service in my Ubuntu server and hosting on the MS Azure VM instance. 
Everything went well, except for one thing when I run the IPFS as service using systemd.

Here is the error that I caught it from the log file.

```
    Aug 17 01:56:25 UbuntuTest systemd[1]: Started IPFS daemon.
Aug 17 01:56:25 UbuntuTest systemd[1]: ipfs.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=217/USER
Aug 17 01:56:25 UbuntuTest systemd[1]: ipfs.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 17 01:56:25 UbuntuTest systemd[1]: ipfs.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 17 01:56:26 UbuntuTest systemd[1]: ipfs.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 17 01:56:26 UbuntuTest systemd[1]: Stopped IPFS daemon.
Aug 17 01:56:26 UbuntuTest systemd[1]: Started IPFS daemon.
Aug 17 01:56:26 UbuntuTest systemd[1]: ipfs.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=217/USER
Aug 17 01:56:26 UbuntuTest systemd[1]: ipfs.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 17 01:56:26 UbuntuTest systemd[1]: ipfs.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 17 01:56:26 UbuntuTest systemd[1]: ipfs.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 17 01:56:26 UbuntuTest systemd[1]: Stopped IPFS daemon.
Aug 17 01:56:26 UbuntuTest systemd[1]: Started IPFS daemon.
Aug 17 01:56:26 UbuntuTest systemd[1]: ipfs.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=217/USER
Aug 17 01:56:26 UbuntuTest systemd[1]: ipfs.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 17 01:56:26 UbuntuTest systemd[1]: ipfs.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 17 01:56:26 UbuntuTest systemd[1]: ipfs.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 17 01:56:26 UbuntuTest systemd[1]: Stopped IPFS daemon.
Aug 17 01:56:26 UbuntuTest systemd[1]: Started IPFS daemon.
Aug 17 01:56:26 UbuntuTest systemd[1]: ipfs.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=217/USER
Aug 17 01:56:26 UbuntuTest systemd[1]: ipfs.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 17 01:56:26 UbuntuTest systemd[1]: ipfs.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 17 01:56:26 UbuntuTest systemd[1]: ipfs.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 17 01:56:26 UbuntuTest systemd[1]: Stopped IPFS daemon.
Aug 17 01:56:26 UbuntuTest systemd[1]: ipfs.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 17 01:56:26 UbuntuTest systemd[1]: Failed to start IPFS daemon
```

.

The log file it seems no longer generate info. 
Why does that happen?

When I run with ipfs daemon and it works well without error.
Please advise.
Thank you

Comment: Seems to me you're looking for [ubuntu.se] instead, as this isn't really a programming related question.

Comment: Can u share all the steps you followed .